# C++ win forms how to print out a void * in textbox?

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++

How can I print out in textbox a `void *` value?

Here is the code:

I've been trying casting but nothing works since it's using System String.

```
uintptr_t offsetFromBuffer = (uintptr_t)internalAddress - (uintptr_t)&buffer;       
void * healthDecAddress = (void*)(currentChunk + offsetFromBuffer);
richTextBox1->Text = healthDecAddress; // how can I do it right?
```

Comment: If it’s `void*` it has no type. First you’ll have to figure out the actual type it points to.

Comment: Choose one language.

Comment: seems like its a uinptr_t pointer.

Comment: some one told me to use :  `std::to_string((uintptr_t)healthDecAddress)` worked but gives wrong value :"to_string" meant to convert int in to string the healthDecaddress is a address from memory so it is Hex number.
i guess that using to_string causing the healthDecaddress losing the actual hex value and its printing normal numbers 0 to 9. here is my cod `   richTextBox1->Text = "Fount the adress" + Environment::NewLine;
   String^ MyString = gcnew String(std::to_string((uintptr_t)&healthDecAddress).c_str());
   richTextBox1->Text = "addr " + MyString + Environment::NewLine; `

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, if it's a `void *` then it has type `void *`.  Moreover, if it's a valid pointer then the thing it points to can and probably does have a type; the pointer type just does not carry that information.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://imgur.com/a/aWzT9qn).  in the image you can see the output and you can also see that after to_string something is going wrong there. what i am trying to do is to print on richtexbox the the value of the healthdecaddress the same as in the picture so since c++ win forms using System string i ma trying some how to make it work and no luck so far :(

Comment: @JohnBollinger That’s what I said.

Answer (score 0):

A `void*` is a pointer to an incomplete type the can't be completed. So it makes no sense to handle the data to that the pointer points. But you can add the pointer value to the text box. You have to convert the pointer value to a text for that purpose.

```
TCHAR PointerValue[20];
stprintf_s(PointerValue, 20, "%08X", healthDecAddress );
```

The text in the variable PointerValue can be added to the text box.

Comment: thank you for reply. which library stprintf_s function use  ? since its gives undefined error of stprintf_s